# StructureMap Child Container

Tags: structuremap

I was Implementing Child Container in Spring, Autofac, StructureMap. I was successful in Spring.NET and Autofac, but I was not able to build a Child Container in StructureMap.
The following code is supposed to give me a Child Container.

```
    StructureMap.Container container = new Container();
    var childContainer = container.GetNestedContainer();
```

But its `GetNestedContainer()` does not pull any transient objects from parent container. Does anyone have any idea how to build a child Container for StructureMap Container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because by design StructureMap only pulls non-transient objects from the parent container.

See [this explanation](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2010/02/10/nested-containers-in-structuremap-2-6-1/) of nested containers, for further details and examples of usage scenarios.

Comment: Yeah, I got that point from Jeremy's blog itself. I am just asking if there is a way to build a child Container which has all the objects in parent Container. Of course, we ll have to deal with pluginGraph and pipelineGraphs.